# Part identify - unknown and no information

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I'm looking for datasheet or information about this IC

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: identification question GREATLY benefit from you telling us in which context you did get that? Was it in a radar device? Or a microwave oven? Or in a computer? Or among replacement parts for airplanes? Or...

Comment: but honestly, PLCC + ceramic + uncommon vendor symbol: this might be super custom and there will very very likely not be any datasheet.

Comment: by the way, [manufacturer is probably Sames](https://www.elnec.com/en/support/ic-logos/manufacturer-description/?manuf=Sames), [website](https://www.sames.co.za/). This sadly doesn't say much, they also offer packaging services: this might be a completely custom chip by a third party packaged by Sames' subcontractor, or it might be a [custom design](https://www.sames.co.za/customer-specific-ics/) by Sames, or anything in between. We can practically preclude the existence of a datasheet! It's a custom chip house.

Comment: So, for whoever ordered this made, it was probably quite expensive, for you, it's probably trash.

Comment: No have additional information.

Comment: so, why would you then want to know?

Answer (score 1):

Best guess is a [Sames SA9109B](https://www.sames.co.za/wp-content/uploads/pdf/legacy/SA9109B.pdf), the logo and the number matches (but not the letters), and the package is PLCC-44, as well.

However, Sames is a [custom IC design house](https://www.sames.co.za/customer-specific-ics/), so chances are this is a modified version, or maybe even completely custom and unrelated!

Question is how useful a "kWh meter with integrated seven-segment LCD display driver" is in 2022. You'd need a matching LCD – the connection matrix for the segments doesn't strike me as "usual" – but I'm by no means an LCD expert – so if you don't have such an LCD already, you'd need it custom-made, at which point simply using any modern microntroller with one differential ADC channel and a single ended one (or three single-ended ones – not like any of this is magic) and an integrated LCD driver would be less work and lower cost.